Description of all biholomorphic maps from annulus
Consider the collection $\mathcal{C}$ of all maps $f \colon B_1 -\overline{B}_\beta \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is biholomorphic onto its image. Is this collection $\mathcal{C}$ path-connected?
In particular, I am curious about the following question: given a doubly connected smooth $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$, does there exists a continuous family of biholomorphic maps $f_t \colon B_1 -\overline{B}_{\beta} \to \mathbb{C}$, $0\leq t \leq 1$, such that

$f_0(z)=z$,
$f_1$ maps $B_1 - \overline{B}_{\beta}$ onto $\Omega$,

where $\beta$ is picked so that $B_1 - \overline{B}_{\beta}$ is biholomorphic to $\Omega$?

Not "modulus of continuity" but "conformal modulus". What topology are you using to define continuity? Uniform convergence on compacts?

See the answer here. If you use the topology of uniform convergence on compacts, the Alex answered your question.

Do you understand that modulus of continuity and conformal modulus are totally different concepts?

@MoisheKohan Sorry, can you explain the difference? I only know modulus of continuity from Rudin. And yes, Uniform convergence on compacts.

Google "conformal modulus".

@MoisheKohan I will do my search. Meanwhile, in the link, the family of maps is only quasi-conformal. I am looking for maps with better differentiability.

No, you misunderstood the answer.

@MoisheKohan That is wonderful news! In that case, can you post an answer explaining it when you got time? I do not know any expert in the topic that can explain it to me.

The answer is given in the link provided by @Moishe Kogan. If you have any specific question about this answer, I can explain.
